# How to Print the Postorder Traversal of a Binary Tree Given the Preorder and Inorder Traversals?

Tags: c++, binary-tree, inorder, preorder, postorder

I was given a task of trying to print the postorder traversal of a binary tree when you are given the preorder and the inorder traversals.

I went online to search up the problem, but the only results that I found was this [GeekForGeeks article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-postorder-from-given-inorder-and-preorder-traversals/). However, I found this article quite confusing and I didn't understand how to solve this problem even after reading the article. Can someone help simplify the article into simpler words? Thanks!

Comment: Two things: First is that post-, pre-, and in-order traversals of trees are part of the very basics of any beginners algorithms and data-structures class. Your books or your teacher should have taught it to you. The second thing is that the site you link to have very bad reputation among experienced programmers. It tend to give out bad advice, and show bad code as examples, sometimes even directly invalid code. Please don't use it. The Internet is overflowing with tutorials and examples of tree traversals. It should not be hard to find more information if your class is lacking.

Comment: With all that said, if you're given an in-order and a pre-order traversal function for the tree, it should not be hard to infer or deduce how a post-order traversal should work. All three functions all follow a very simple and deductible pattern. Especially if you know that "pre" means "before", "in" means "in between", and "post" means "after" (which should also be easy to deduce from examples).

Comment: Yea, I know that pre-order traversal is basically you process the root, the the left subtree, and then the right subtree, and in-order traversal is where you first process the left subtree then the root, and then the right subtree, but how I still don't understand how that helps with finding the post-order traversal, and I already searched online, but the GeeksForGeeks article was the only thing that I found...

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude No you are not given in-order and pre-order *functions*. You are given output of those functions.

Comment: So you know that pre-order processes the current node first, and that in-order processes the current node between left and right traversals. What do you *think* "post" traversal would do? There's really only one place left where you can process the current node, if it's not done first or in between.

Comment: Well yea, it's right, left, then root, but how do we deduce that using pre and in? If you want, you can post an answer, and I could mark that as the solution.

Comment: (1) Given the preorder, can you find the root of the tree? (2) Given the root and the inorder, can you find the left and the right subtrees in it? (3) Given the left and the right subtrees *in the inorder*, can you find the same *in the preorder*?

Comment: Ohhhh I see! Thanks! I just solve the problem! It would be great if you could post a solution so I can give you credit! :D

Comment: Side note : in general do not trust geek for geeks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is impossible in the general case. Consider:

```
  A
A   B
```

Let's label these as

```
  1
2   3
```

- Preorder traversal AAB  (1, 2, 3)
- Inorder traversal AAB (2, 1, 3)
- Postorder traversal ABA (2, 3, 1)

Now consider:

```
A (1)
  A (2)
    B (3)
```

- Preorder: AAB (1, 2, 3)
- Inorder: AAB (1, 2, 3)
- Postorder: BAA (3, 2, 1)

Given preorder and inorder trees as AAB will not have an unambigous postorder representation.

Comment: The usual condition is that all nodes are unique.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Yes, I intentionally removed that unnecessary condition lest this post be blatantly incorrect.